# Mysql creating new user: is omitting "@<host>" part OK when remote access will always use an ssh shell?

Tags: mysql

Many examples for creating a mysql user show the form:

CREATE USER User@localhost;

or

CREATE USER User@%;

However a few show show just

CREATE USER User;

with no host specification.

I am guessing the latter defaults to an implicit '@localhost'.
Which would mean it would not be possible to log in as that 'User' from a remote mysql server instance. **Is that correct?**

**In the case where the DB will only be accessed by local shells on the same host as the DB (e.g. an ssh shell connection), is there any good reason to add '@localhost' or '@%'?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The host name part of the account name, if omitted, defaults to '%'.

Excerpt from the [Official Documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-user.html). It means you can access a remote MySQL server via this new user.

Comment: Which means that you should set the host explicitly to `@localhost` if you never need to connet remotely.